# Catch event when Ember data has been loaded

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to have specific instructions running when my data coming from the server via Ember data is fully loaded. I want to redirect the ember app to a different route following the number of items the server returned.
I have tried to use the promise returned by the `findAll()` method, but the function gets fired too soon as the data has not been loaded yet. Then I tried to use the event `didLoad` but it never gets fired.
Has anyone any thoughts for this ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The records should be available by the time the promise is resolved if you are following the pattern below.  Additionally the afterModel hook in a route will have the model resolved.  Now this is a little different if you have async relationships or some other structure, if that's the case you need to specify more information.

```
var blah = this.get('store').find('apples');
blah.then(function(records){
  //records are loaded at this point.
  console.log("Loaded " + records.get('length') + " records");
});
```

Comment: I never got it working but then updated Ember and Ember data, and now the behavior of the promises is the one you described. Thank you